# Sending mail via aws ses with attachment in node.js

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-web-services, email-attachments, amazon-ses

Does anyone have some example of how to send email with attachment in `node.js` with aws ses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great mailing library called ˇNodemailerˇ it also has support for the Amazon SES. Here is a small example of how to send e-mail with attachment https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/examples/ses.js

But be aware that Amazon has strange errors when your email sending fails.

Comment: Now [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#use-a-transport-plugin) has a separate [SES transport module](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-ses-transport).

Comment: Bear in mind nodemailer does not support SESv2. This limits the size of the message (and therefore attachments) to 10MB.
- https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1165
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/quotas.html

Answer (score 27):

If you want to avoid suffering, you have to use SES wrapped in Nodemailer. Using the AWS SDK directly, you can't send attachments with `ses.sendEmail`, you have to use `ses.sendRawEmail`, which is awful because you have to form the raw E-mail with headers and what-not, and even after I did that, I had a weird error where duplicate E-mails were being sent...

`npm install nodemailer`

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

async function scheduledEmail () {
  let usefulData = 'some,stuff,to,send';
  
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: new AWS.SES({ region: 'us-east-1', apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
  });
  
  let text = 'Attached is a CSV of some stuff.';

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Some name" <someone@example.com>',
    to: "someone_else@example.com",
    subject: "Hello",                // Subject line
    text: text,                      // plaintext version
    html: '<div>' + text + '</div>', // html version
    attachments: [{
        filename: "usefulData.csv",
        content: usefulData
    }]
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>
  return info; // or something
}
```

There are plenty of examples for other ways to set attachments:
https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/

If you're still in the SES sandbox mode, both the to/from addresses have to be verified. Apply to get out of the sandbox mode on the SES Sending statistics page.

Comment: A-Sharabiani: content can be many things. Refer to the nodemailer docs for info: https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use the AWS SESv2 without too much suffering but more directly than using NodeMailer you can easily build the mime data using this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mimetext)

The `Content` part of the `SendEmailCommand` would look like:

```
Content: {
   Raw: {
      Data: Buffer.from(clientMsg.asRaw(), 'utf8')
   }
},
```

In provided example on module they also demonstrate how to pull the to/from emails from the MIME message to avoid retyping.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this library really works! I was trying to solve attachments almost whole day and with this library it was in minute.