# How to send an HTML and PDF attachment in ses email

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ses

For my application, I am writing an lambda function in node js for sending email from ses. This email is triggered when S3 bucket gets an image. And email should contains only html content as and an pdf attachment. I have tried with sendRawEmail function, however it is sending all the things in email body (from, to, content type). Is there any proper function for this, it will be good if I get a good tutorial for this

Comment: Have you looked at the answers to these questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781486/upload-jpg-image-attachment-in-mail-using-aws-ses-from-node-js  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042835/sending-mail-via-aws-ses-with-attachment-in-node-js

Comment: Thank you Mark. It helps me to move forward